# What if no Model fits and no non-parametric alternative exists?

Tags: repeated-measures, data-transformation, poisson-distribution, small-sample

I'm doing analysis on data from an ecological field study. I have fields (n=12) of different age. I treat age as a factor (age class) having 4 levels (1,3,5,and 7/8 years old). Hence the number of field replicates is very low n=3. I sampled each field two times, one sampling in the first year and one in the second. Hence I've got repeated measurements.

I want to know if certain faunal groups increase over time, either during sampling period or across the age classes. I also use both terms in interaction.

I have three examples where it is hard for me to decide which assumption I should choose for the error distribution:

1. No count data - the gaussian model is bad
2. Count data - the gaussian model is bad
3. Count data - the gaussian model is good

"Good" and "bad" refers to the residual plots, used for model diagnostics.

My data:

```
 df.ex1 <- structure(list(age_class = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("B_Sp_young", "C_Sp_int1", "D_Sp_int2", "E_Sp_old"
), class = "factor"), samcam = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2", "4"), class = "factor"), fiel.ID = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), 
    ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L
    )), .Names = c("age_class", "samcam", "fiel.ID", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")

 df.rsp1 <- structure(list(CI = c(42.8571428571429, 33.3333333333333, 7.69230769230769, 
36, 13.3333333333333, 8.57142857142857, 13.3333333333333, 9.56521739130435, 
60.655737704918, 12.3809523809524, 0, 9.52380952380952, 57.8947368421053, 
13.5135135135135, 41.4634146341463, 32.0754716981132, 26.3157894736842, 
18.8405797101449, 72.4137931034483, 0, 36.8421052631579, 16.6666666666667, 
7.69230769230769, 81.8181818181818), Apc = c(0, 0, 0, 10, 20, 
133, 0, 14, 7, 0, 0, 15, 51, 43, 11, 0, 156, 20, 6, 206, 8, 146, 
9, 8), Hoplo = c(781, 3492, 533, 0, 20, 692, 6, 176, 0, 17, 828, 
246, 1098, 2236, 477, 12, 140, 269, 62, 206, 0, 12, 473, 15)), .Names = c("CI", 
"Apc", "Hoplo"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my Analysis:

```
outlier <- list(nema.CI <- 1:24, #-24?
                spec.Apc <- 1:24,
                spec.Hoplo <- -2)

# Formulas for "global models"
fml.glb <- as.formula(y ~ age_class + samcam + age_class:samcam + (1|field.ID)) # + pH + cnratio + mc + ats1 
fml.glb.log <- as.formula(log1p(y) ~ age_class + samcam + age_class:samcam + (1|field.ID)) #+ pH + cnratio + mc + ats1 

# Set optimizer function gor glmm
con = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5), calc.derivs = TRUE, check.conv.grad="ignore")

# Case1
df.ex1$y <- df.rsp1$CI
df.ex2 <- df.ex1[outlier[[1]],]
M1.A <- lmer(fml.glb, df.ex2)
M1.B <- lmer(fml.glb.log, df.ex2)

# Case2
df.ex1$y <- df.rsp1$Apc
df.ex2 <- df.ex1[outlier[[2]],]
M2.A <- lmer(fml.glb, df.ex2)
M2.B <- glmer(fml.glb, family = "poisson", df.ex2, control = con)
M2.C <- lmer(fml.glb.log, df.ex2)

# Case3
df.ex1$y <- df.rsp1$Hoplo
df.ex2 <- df.ex1[outlier[[3]],]
M3.A <- lmer(fml.glb, df.ex2)
M3.B <- glmer(fml.glb, family = "poisson", df.ex2, control = con)
M3.C <- lmer(fml.glb.log, df.ex2)

# Store Models in a list
ls.glbModels <- list(M1.A, M1.B, M2.A, M2.B, M2.C, M3.A, M3.B, M3.C)
names(ls.glbModels) <- c("M1.A_CI", "M1.B_CI", "M2.A_Apc", "M2.B_Apc", "M2.C_Apc", "M3.A_Hoplo", "M3.B_Hoplo", "M3.C_Hoplo")
```

Then I do Model Diagnostics via residual plots and normal QQ plots for each type of residuals ("pearson","response", "deviance"):

```
windows(record=TRUE)

for(k in 1:8){ 

  E1 <- resid(ls.glbModels[[k]], type="pearson")
  E2 <- resid(ls.glbModels[[k]], type="response")
  E3 <- residuals(ls.glbModels[[k]], type="deviance")
  F1 <- fitted(ls.glbModels[[k]], type="response")
  P1 <- predict(ls.glbModels[[k]], type="response")

  par(mfrow=c(3,3),
      mar=c(4,4.5,1,2),
      oma=c(0,0,2,0))

  # Plot fitted vs. residuals
  p1 <- scatter.smooth(F1, E1, cex.lab = 1.5, xlab="Fitted values", ylab="Pearson Residuals")
  abline(h = 0, v=0, lty=2); text(F1, E1, labels = row.names(df.ex1), pos = 4)
  scatter.smooth(F1, E2, cex.lab = 1.5, xlab="Fitted values", ylab="Response Residuals")
  abline(h = 0, v=0, lty=2); text(F1, E1, labels = row.names(df.ex1), pos = 2)
  scatter.smooth(F1, E3, cex.lab = 1.5, xlab="Fitted values", ylab="Deviance Residuals")
  abline(h = 0, v=0, lty=2)

  # plot predicted vs. residuals
  scatter.smooth(log(predict(ls.glbModels[[k]])), E1, cex.lab = 1.5, xlab="log Predicted values", ylab="Pearson Residuals")
  abline(h = 0, v=0, lty=2); text(log(predict(ls.glbModels[[k]])), E1, labels = row.names(df.ex1), pos = 4)
  scatter.smooth(log(predict(ls.glbModels[[k]])), E2, cex.lab = 1.5, xlab="log Predicted values", ylab="Response Residuals")
  abline(h = 0, v=0, lty=2)
  scatter.smooth(log(predict(ls.glbModels[[k]])), E3, cex.lab = 1.5, xlab="log Predicted values", ylab="Deviance Residuals")
  abline(h = 0, v=0, lty=2)

  # Normal QQ Plots
  qq <- qqnorm(E1)
  qqline(E1)
  text(qq$x, qq$y, row.names(df.exp2), pos=4)

  qq <- qqnorm(E2)
  qqline(E2)
  text(qq$x, qq$y, row.names(df.exp2), pos=2)

  qqnorm(E3)
  qqline(E3)

  title(paste(k,names(ls.glbModels)[k]), outer=TRUE)
}
```

In general i use the plots for pearson residuals. But I'm not completely sure about the value of each individual plot. Normally I'm also plotting residuals against Variables IN and NOT IN the Model. But gernerally there are big Differences in spread between the groups (I think that is also called "Heteroscedasticity"). Furthermore I decided not to use additional Variables and no Varaiable Selection procedure is performe. Since i think what I'm interessted in is Hypothesis testing not Model selection.
My Hypothesis are:
Numbers of Inividuals Increase over the age classes and with sampling campaigns.
In the ideal case I'll see an increase in both. I.e., older fields contain more Individuals, and the increase is also observable within the period of one year.
For the CI Index it is the same expectation.

Now to my Question:
In general i got the best residual plots for log(x+1) transformed data! However, i read and heard a lot about NOT transforming data prior to analysis. 
Especially count data should be analysed using poisson models. But when I use poisson, normally the residuals decrease with fitted values or have other strange patterns. Overdispersion is just erased when using random term (1|ID), like Ben Bolker recommented and seems to me to be a "hack" comparable to log(x+1) transformation. The log(x+1) transformation even finds its way back to lmm's as the log-normal distribution which is not the gaussian distribution with log-link!! I read many posts where people said negative binomial is an alternative to poisson, if the latter is bad. However, I experienced, that the same analysis delivered different results at different computers with the Negbin models. Furthermore many Post Analyses are not supporting negbin models in R (i.e. afex::mixed(), lsmeans, glht(),...). Additionally much of the results depend on the package used: i.e. glmmADMB gives most of the times good negbin models, but differs strongly from the results of glmer.nb.

What about not-count data, when gaussian models seem to be heteroscedastic i terms of increasing variation with fitted values? Poisson is a discrete distribution! 
Or the other way round, what if the gaussian model fits well to count data?
I think in this case i should stay with gaussian because i read there is no global rule to apply poisson models to all count data. 
Normally i would say, if no model fits well, do non-parametric Analyses! However there is no non-parametric alternative, when dealing with repeated measurements!! (Or is nparL? but how should one explain that in a mat-meth section?)

I guess in my case the solution would be to say: 
"OK, i've got only very small data set with very small number of replicates for each group, so i would probably not find the "perfect" model, if this exists at all. So I will stay with gaussian if that is "Good" and take poisson if gaussian is not "Good". I leave log(x+1) transformation out because glms are supposed to be superior over transformation."

What is your opinion?

Comment: When datasets are so small, sometimes it is sufficient to simply plot the data.

Comment: Thanks, I totally agree with you. Plot the data an draw inference from a biological-scientific view! However I'm expected to to some analyses. Most of the researchers I know believe ANOVA is sufficient with at least 3 replicates, and most of them are in a higher position. I thought repeated measurments would really help me out of this dilemma by increasing the statistical power.